# Sanitising include file before having them executed using a whitelist

Tags: php, include, sanitization, whitelist

Is it possible to sanitise an include before it is executed to make sure that it exists on the server?

I want to avoid attackers compromising the file path using some sort of whitelist, is this possible?

My include looks like this:

```
require_once('../includes/front/header.php');
```

Comment: The whole point of `require` is that the execution stops if it is not found because the file is required. If you do not want that, just use `include` in combination with `file_exists()` or `is_file()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How could the path be compromised? (Unless your `require_once` contains user input - avoid this!)

You could just check if the file exists using `file_exists`:

eg.

```
if(file_exists('../includes/front/header.php')) {
  require_once('../includes/front/headers.php');
}
```

If you did want a whitelist though you could just create an `array` of **allowed** path/filenames and then just use `in_array` to check its validity.

Comment: ok so your saying there is no need to create a whitelist because there is no user input?

Comment: ok could you just tell in what situation would require_once contain user input? :s

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function of PHP and your whitelist:

```
$allowed_files = array('../includes/front/header.php','../includes/front/footer.php');
$include_file = <string with file/path>; //EG '../includes/front/header.php'

if (in_array($include_file,$allowed_files && file_exists($include_file)) {
    require_once($include_file);
}
```

If your path is hardcoded into the PHP script and not accepting user input for a filename, then you should not need to sanitize your own filename/path

Answer (score 0):

You could write you're own include which could validate against a list of 'allowed' paths.

i.e. using the above, but wrap it in a function.